# How to convert daily to monthly netcdf files

Tags: python, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I have downloaded climate model output in the form of netcdf files with one variable (pr) for the whole world with a daily time-step. My final goal is to have monthly data for Europe.

I have never used netcdf files before and all the specific software for netcdf I could find doesn't seems to work in windows. Since I programme in R, I tried using the ncdf4 package but run into memory size problems (my files are around 2Gb)...  I am now trying the netCDF4 module in python (first time I am using python - so go easy on me).

I have managed to install everything and found some code online to import the dataset:

```
nc_fid = Dataset(nc_f, 'r')  
# Extract data from NetCDF file
lats = nc_fid.variables['lat'][:]
lons = nc_fid.variables['lon'][:]
time = nc_fid.variables['time'][:]
pp  = nc_fid.variables['pr'][:]
```

However all the tutorials I found are on how to make a netcdf file... I have no idea how to aggregate this daily rainfall (variable pr) into monthly. Also, I have different types of calender in different files, but I don't even know how to access that information:

```
time.calendar
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'calendar'
```

Please help, I don't want to have to learn Linux just so I can sort-out some data :(

Comment: Tell more about the input netCDF daily data.  Is it one file per day?  Or all in one file?  What do you mean by different calendars?

Comment: There are several years in each file and the whole time-series for each climate model is in a handful of files (but if you can tell me how to do it for each file that would be already very helpful). I need to take the calendar type in consideration because once I know how to do it I will be running the code for outputs of different climate models, and they have different calendars (standard, 360 days...)

Answer (score 3):

Why not avoid programming entirely and use [NCO](http://nco.sf.net) which supplies the **ncrcat** command that aggregates data thusly:

```
ncrcat day*.nc month.nc
```

Voilà. See more **ncrcat** examples [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncrcat).

Added 20160628: If instead of a month-long timeseries you want a monthly average then use the same command only with **ncra** instead of **ncrcat**. The manual explains things like this.

Comment: A little question for you, I did what you posted but it just merged my daily NetCDF but did not do the monthly average... can you suggest something?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a daily timestep and you want to calculate the monthly mean then you can do

```
cdo monmean input_yyyy.nc output_yyyy.nc
```

It sounds as if you have several of these files, so you will need to merge them with

```
cdo mergetime file_*.nc timeseries.nc
```

where the * is a wildcard for the years.